# How to retrieve User's followed Spotify API with angular 8?

Tags: html, angular

[image]

How can I get total number that User followed with `Spotify API`?

I got my followers and all the top tracks that I currently listened but I don't know how to retrieve total following and total playlists that I created.

Here is my `user.service.ts`:

```
export class UserService {
  private accessToken: string;
  private loggedIn: boolean;
  private userProfile: UserProfile;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public setLoggedInUser(accessToken: string): Promise<UserProfile> {
    return new Promise<UserProfile>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.accessToken = accessToken;

      this.getSpotifyUserProfile().subscribe(
        (res) => {
          this.loggedIn = true;
          this.userProfile = res;
          resolve(this.userProfile);
        },
        (err) => {
          this.logout();
          reject(err);
        }
      );
    });
  }

  private getSpotifyUserProfile(): Observable<any> {
    const endpoint = environment.spotifyApi.host + "me";

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.accessToken}`,
      }),
    };

    return this.http.get(endpoint, httpOptions);
  }

  public getAccessToken(): string {
    return this.accessToken;
  }

  public getLoginStatus(): boolean {
    return this.loggedIn;
  }

  public getUserProfile(): UserProfile {
    return this.userProfile;
  }

  getUserFollowing(): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.accessToken}`,
      }),
    };

    return this.http.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/following?type=artist");
  }

  public logout(): void {
    this.loggedIn = false;
    localStorage.removeItem("ng-spotify-access-token");
  }
}
```

and here is my `user.component.ts`:

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  private user_name: string;
  private user_follower: number;
  private user_image: Array<any>;
  constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {
    this.user_name = this.userService.getUserProfile().display_name;
    this.user_follower = this.userService.getUserProfile().followers;
    this.user_image = this.userService.getUserProfile().images;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getFollowing();
  }

  getFollowing() {
    let observable = this.userService.getUserFollowing();
    observable.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

and here is my `user.component.html`:

```
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li class="list-inline-item">
      <h5>{{user_follower.total}}</h5>
      <p>Followers</p>
    </li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">
      <h5></h5>
      <p>Following</p>
    </li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">
      <h5></h5>
      <p>Playlists</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I'm getting an error by the return API from my `getFollowing()`

> core.js:6014 ERROR  HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status:
>   401, statusText: "OK", url:
>   "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/following?type=artist", ok: false, …}
>   error: {error: {…}} headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0),
>   lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ} message: "Http failure response for
>   https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/following?type=artist: 401 OK" name:
>   "HttpErrorResponse" ok: false status: 401 statusText: "OK" url:
>   "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/following?type=artist"
>   **proto**: HttpResponseBase

Comment: 401 error means unauthorized. Is the token your sending valid?

Comment: Hmm I used token from `getSpotifyUserProfile()`